# Jenkins job pauses for 15 minutes

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, windows-server-2012-r2, jenkins-build-flow

I have a job running on a WindowsServer2012R2 agent. The job is pausing between 2 plugins ([BuildNameSetter](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Build+Name+Setter+Plugin) v1.6.8 and [DiscardOldBuilds](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Discard+Old+Build+plugin) v1.0.5) as you can see below:

```
    13:05:25 Set build name.
    13:05:25 New build name is '5.0.811.0'
    13:20:21 Discard old builds...
```

I've started to notice this strange behavior after upgrading Jenkins Master from 2.89 to 2.190.3. 
It's frustrating to see your job taking a 15 minutes nap!

Is this a server side issue or a agent side one?  
Can someone give me some hints about how to tackle this problem?  
Did you experience something similar?

Answer (score 0):

- you could have a look at jenkins central logs /log/all to see if there is any java stacktrace error in there
- Then you should first try to isolate the issue. try deactivating the build name setter step first. then try to disable the discard old build. then enable build name setter again and keep discard old build deactivated
- now you know which plugin is causing the issue try to downgrade or upgrade the plugin that makes your build hang
- if the issue comes from discard old build, I would try to remove clean the job's workspace  and remove builds manually
- look for your issue on jenkins's jira system, upvote. create a ticket if you have not found another user experiencing the same issue
- Finally you should be able to find workarounds for these plugins

Comment: I have deactivated both plugins and the pause is still happening.
Funny thing is that I have 2 different jobs that are almost identical and only the name is different. One is pausing and the other is not.

Comment: The actual plugin that triggers the pause is [Log-Parser](https://plugins.jenkins.io/log-parser/)

Comment: Glad you could find the root cause. Now I would check if there is already an issue on https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-62182?jql=project%20%3D%20JENKINS%20AND%20component%20%3D%20log-parser-plugin and open one if there is none yet. Also maybe the regex you are currently using with the plugin could be updated to trigger more efficient search. I never used this plugin

Answer (score 0):

Today I've upgraded Jenkins to a newer version (2.263.2) on the Jenkins server and the 15 minutes pause dissapeared.